# AngularJS - Route - How to match star (*) as a path

Tags: javascript, routes, angularjs

I'm making a resource viewer app, but the problem is that i tried to match  `when("/!/:resourceUrl")`.

It works fine if the resource url is something like `/path`, but how can I make something like a `/path/to/the/resource`.
I don't know how much paths will it take, so I can't do `.when("/!/:path1/:path2/:path3")`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of angular-1.2 you can do this:

```
when("/!/:resourceUrl*")
```

http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/docs/api/ngRoute.$routeProvider

In particular the documentation gives the following example:

For example, routes like `/color/:color/largecode/:largecode*\/edit` will match `/color/brown/largecode
/code/with/slashs/edit` and extract:

- `color: brown`
- `largecode: code/with/slashs`

Comment: How do you extract it in JS in the next page?

Answer (score 4):

As of now, AngularJS doesn't support regular expressions in routes.

Check these links: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/918, https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/972

Comment: Thanks. You can sugest me an idea or how to archive my goal. I just have 2 routes, /login and /!. The /!/:resourcePath is the path to the resource the user want to see, but I dont want to make a /!/path2Fto2Fthe2Fresource because it's to ugly.

Comment: What do you mean saying resource? Is that some data that has its long 'ugly' ID?

Comment: Yea, well, resource is something like a url of a book, or image, my app is a library, but I want to be able to do something like: http://myapp.com/#/!/javascript/basics/JS_01.pdf so I can get this parameter and look at this direction to show it to the user. The user can bookmark this url to be sharable.

Comment: [UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) supports regular expressions in routes, as well as child routes and some other slick functionality. But the slash matching built into Angular may do the job.