# how to have wildcards in angular routes

Tags: angularjs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AngularJS - Route - How to match star (*) as a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685085/angularjs-route-how-to-match-star-as-a-path)

How do I specify wildcards in my routes -

```
$routeProvider
      .when('/admin/*', {
        templateUrl: 'admin.html',
        controller: 'AdminCtrl'
      })
```

So the above should work for /admin/users and /admin/users/1 or /admin/org/3. So there could be either one or two levels of path after admin. How do I do it ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Currently AngularJS does not support regular expression in routes.

You can workaround as follows

```
 app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
                 .when('/admin', {templateUrl: 'admin.html', controller: 'AdminCtrl'})
                 .when('/admin/:type', {templateUrl: 'admin.html', controller: 'AdminCtrl'})
                 .when('/admin/:type/:id', {templateUrl: 'admin.html', controller: 'AdminCtrl'});  
 }]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/tBumW2oEqki2sEl1hjSc?p=preview

IMO, it is good idea to have the separate controller for both admin and users, unless otherwise you have some special requirement.

Comment: [UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing) supports regex in routes, among other cool things.