# Does AngularJS have required route segments?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I've got routing that looks like this:

```
.when "/:locale",
  templateUrl: "/views/index.html"
...
.otherwise redirectTo: "/en"
```

The issue is that the first route also matches `/`. Is there a way to add required route segments, so that `/:locale` would only match if there's actually non-empty string?

I could probably listen to `$routeChangeStart` and implement `otherwise` condition there, but it would be much easier if I could do it all in a single place.

Comment: see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216565/how-to-have-wildcards-in-angular-routes

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't really answer my question. I'm not asking about wildcards, but single route segment that's not optional. I don't have any controller for that action, as it's only rendering a template and doesn't have any logic.

Comment: It looks like it was broken recently in 1.2.0 RC2: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/04cebcc133c8b433a3ac5f72ed19f3631778142b#commitcomment-3866914

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was broken in 1.2.0 RC2 by  [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/04cebcc133c8b433a3ac5f72ed19f3631778142b) commit and there's already a [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3602) to fix it that will land in 1.2.0 RC3.

Comment: Such is life when you're living on the bleeding edge.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , sorry i can not understand your need , but i hope this will work

```
.when "",
  templateUrl: "/page.html"
.when "/",
  templateUrl: "/page.html"
.when "/:locale",
  templateUrl: "/views/index.html"
...
.otherwise redirectTo: "/"
```