# I want my Blog-title in url using Angular Js routing to boost my page SEO

Tags: angularjs, seo, angularjs-ng-route

I have a page "detail.html", which is for displaying blog detail. Same page "detail.html" dynamically fetch blog detail for all users and their blogs. 
Page "detail.html" has blog title, images and description. I want to use blog title in my URL. 
I want this to boost my page SEO. is there any way to achieve this in angular routing.

```
For example-
www.domain.com/wonderfull-outing-with-friends
www.domain.com/when-i-found-the-truth
these two blogs displaying on same page -detail.html
```

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: @kelin I got the answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216565/how-to-have-wildcards-in-angular-routes

Answer (score 0):

> you can do it by using route parameter.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
             .when('/admin', {templateUrl: 'admin.html', controller: 'AdminCtrl'})
             .when('/admin/:type', {templateUrl: 'admin.html', controller: 'AdminCtrl'})
             .when('/admin/:type/:id', {templateUrl: 'admin.html', controller: 'AdminCtrl'}); }]);
```