# Angular Routing on encrypted parameter

Tags: c#, angularjs, encryption, angular-routing

I have the following routing:

```
...
when('/sections/:bookID', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/book.html',
        controller: 'bookCtrl'       
    })
...
```

Where bookID is defined as parameter but it is also encrypted and encoded so the resulting URL looks like:

```
/sections/9XhNLs0tI%2fmr67rkJtfhaw%3d%3d
```

The issue is that this routing is not working?

PS: The unencrypted value works just fine. So, I know the routing is working.

The Encoding was made in C# like this:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(encrytedBuffer));
```

Do you know why the routing does not work this value `9XhNLs0tI%2fmr67rkJtfhaw%3d%3d` it looks fine to me?

Comment: when you say its not working to do mean you can't access the variable in your controller or that its not loading the route view at all?

Comment: It is not loading the route at all. It loads the default routing.

Comment: can you post your full route decloration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is it's being decoded to "9XhNLs0tI/mr67rkJtfhaw==." You *should* be able to solve it by double encoding / decoding.

Comment: are you suggesting that :  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value)) will fix the issue?

Comment: @Dalorzo nevermind, you're right. I don't know why but I read that as you being snarky and copy/pasting his existing Url Encoding. Double URL encoding *should* produce 9XhNLs0tI%252fmr67rkJtfhaw%253d%253d

Comment: @Dalarzo I'm pretty sure either would work but I could be off. I haven't had much sleep this week so I'm not exactly firing on all cylinders.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to these characters: "%2f"

There is a post already on this regards:

[Angular JS 'route' doesn't match component with %2F (encoded '/')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630912/angular-js-route-doesnt-match-component-with-2f-encoded)