# angularjs 1.6.0 (latest now) routes not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route, angularjs-1.6

I was expecting to see this question on Stackoverflow but didn't. Apparently I'm the only one having this problem that seems to me to be very common.

I have a basic project I am working on but the routes don't seem to work even though everything I've done so far seems to be right.

I have this piece of html in my `index.html` file:

```
<html>
<head ng-app="myApp"> 
    <title>New project</title>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#/add-quote">Add Quote</a>
    <div ng-view ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my `app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);


app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/add-quote', {
            templateUrl: 'views/add_quote.html',
            controller: 'QuoteCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);
```

Now when I just visit the page, here is what I get in the url:

> http://localhost:8000/admin#!/

and when I click on the `Add quote` button, I get this:

> http://localhost:8000/admin#!/#%2Fadd-quote

What can be the problem here?
Thanks for help

Comment: possibly related? https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aa077e81129c740041438688dff2e8d20c3d7b52

Answer (score 174, accepted):

Simply use hashbang `#!` in the href:

```
 <a href="#!/add-quote">Add Quote</a>
```

---

Due to [aa077e8](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aa077e81129c740041438688dff2e8d20c3d7b52), the default hash-prefix used for $location hash-bang URLs has changed from the empty string (`''`) to the bang (`'!'`).

If you actually want to have no hash-prefix, then you can restore the previous behavior by adding a configuration block to your application:

```
appModule.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS GitHub Pull #14202 Changed default hashPrefix to '!'](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/14202)
- [AngularJS Guide - Migration - aa0077e8](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#commit-aa077e8)

---

*Sorry to get on my high horse but... How did this get released? This is massive, breaking bug. — [@MiloTheGreat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/436725/milothegreat)*

> **The breaking change as by #14202 should be reverted as the reference specification was already officially deprecated #15715**
>
> *I'm going to close this issue because we haven't got any feedback. Feel free to reopen this issue if you can provide new feedback.*
>
> — https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15715#issuecomment-281785369

Comment: Sorry to get on my high horse but...

How did this get released? This is massive, breaking bug.

Comment: @MiloTheGreat feel free to leave your feedback with the AngularJS Team -- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/15715

Answer (score 39):

Simply include the `!` into the `href`:

```
<body>
    <a href="#!/add-quote">Add Quote</a>
    <div ng-view ></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow wasted hours following deprecated tutorials on routing .. all I was missing was the '!'. Thank you!

Comment: With all of the jumpo mumpo about hashes and hashbang I never thought that "!" seems like an illegal character that appears without reference. And if I just accept it and acknowledge it's existence the problem would have been solved.

Comment: Me too... this was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't get routing to work in 1.6.4 so I decided to use angular 1.5.11 and routing works fine although I needed to define all my routings in when(..) functions with trailing "/"

If sticking to an older version of angular is an option for you then consider it since it may save your nerves...

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when("/layoutandviewbox", {
    templateUrl : "views/layout-and-viewbox.html"
})
.when("/basicshapes", {
    templateUrl : "views/basic-shapes.html"
})
.when("/advancedshapes", {
    templateUrl : "views/advanced-shapes.html"
})
.when("/groups", {
    templateUrl : "views/groups.html"
})
.when("/transformations", {
    templateUrl : "views/transformations.html"
})
.when("/effects", {
    templateUrl : "views/effects.html"
})
.when("/", {
    templateUrl : "views/basic-shapes.html"
});
});
```

Comment: How does staying on 1.5 affect upgrading to Angular 2/3/4/5/etc? Does ngUpgrade work from 1.5 to 2+? I'm kinda feeling ngUpgrade may not be viable for us. (yeah this comment will mostly be unseen and howling into the wind)

Answer (score 0):

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
  $routeProvider
    .when('/add-quote', {
      templateUrl: 'views/add_quote.html',
      controller: 'QuoteCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one might Help...

In html or view Page

```
 <body>
       <a href="#/Home.html">Home</a>
       <div ng-view></div>
 </body>
```

In Script Page

```
var app=angular
.module('myModule',['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/Home', {
      templateUrl: 'FolderName/Home.html',
      controller: 'homeCtr'
    })
      $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
     });
```