# ng-view Not working

Tags: html, angularjs

I cannot get the following code to run. I have tried many many things including: `$locationprovider.html5mode(true)` (and a  element in the  of my index.html.)

With this code I get `/#!/index#%2Ffishes` (with my base infront of it) in my URL. With html5mode I would get `#fishes` but the view would not change.

Plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/a2lkCuxMf0ll9e9QAyiv?p=preview

Index:

```
<body  ng-app="VissenApp">
    <div class="AngularWrapper">
        <div ng-view>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

App.js:

```
var app = angular.module("VissenApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
    $routeProvider
    .when("/index", {
        templateUrl : "landing.html",
    controller: "fishesController"
    })
    .when("/fishes", {
        templateUrl : "fishes.html",
        controller: "fishesController"
    })
    .otherwise({
        templateUrl : "landing.html",
controller : "fishesController"
    });

}); 
app.controller('fishesController', function($scope,$location) {
    $scope.toFishes = function () {
        $location.path("/fishes");
    };
});
```

Fishes.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="jumbotron">
    gfhhgfh
    </div>
</div>
```

Landing.html

```
<div class="container-fluid landing_background">
    <div  id="landing_logowrapper" >
            <div  ng-click="toFishes()" id="landing_logobackground" > 
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: None unfortunately.

Comment: seems like a small enough app. In these cases, a plunker reproducing the issue is usually really helpful.

Comment: Where are your html template files placed relative to your app.js?

Comment: I have added a Plunker reproduction. The HTML template files are 1 step back. My JS is in /js/app.js and html files are in root.

Comment: @Kraishan, in your question, check the HTML code of `Landing.html`: there is a closing `</div>` tag. Check also the `network` tab for check if the requests are successful.

Comment: I've edited the main post. Right now the view changes to /fishes. However, if I reload that page obviously it goes to <base>/fishes which does not exist. How to workaround?

Comment: this seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working#comment69623221_41211875.  changing your href to `<a href="#!/fishes" >` seems to solve the issue in the example you posted.

Comment: That changes my URL to: index.html#!%2Ffishes

Comment: Now my page refreshed, using the hasPrefix('') and using #/fishes @Claies