# Angular (1.6.x) routing into chrome to address location

Tags: angularjs, html, google-chrome, angularjs-ng-route, angularjs-1.6

I'm trying to do a simple work in partial view by ng-view.It has four anchor link like sweden, denmark, norway...
If I click one of them then it will show partial page on the index page.But it doesn't work.The browser address location shows something like

`localhost/Angular%20js%20practice/#!#%2Fdenmark`
`localhost/Angular%20js%20practice/#!#%2Fnorway`

But it should be like --- `localhost/Angular%20js%20practice/#/denmark`--- and it will show me denmark partial page view. So what should I do?

```
myApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/sweden',{
        templateUrl:'templates/sweden.html',
        controller: 'myCtrl2'
    })
    .when('/norway',{
        templateUrl:'templates/norway.html',
        controller:'myCtrl2'
    })
    .when('/denmark',{
        templateUrl:'templates/denmark.html',
        controller:'myCtrl2'
    })
    .when('/turkey',{
        templateUrl:'templates/turkey.html',
        controller:'myCtrl2'
    });

});
```

```
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#/sweden">Sweden</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/norway">Norway</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/denmark">Denmark</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/turkey">Turkey</a></li>
    </ul>
<div ng-view></div>
```

Comment: which version of angular?  This behavior was recently changed....

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working

Comment: I'm using  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script> also angular route.

Comment: then the link there is an exact duplicate.  This was changed in angular 1.6.

Comment: Use the solution in [angularjs 1.6.0 (latest now) routes not working](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41213016/5535245).