# Angular seems to transform url path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

it seems like angular is transforming my url path every time I use a hash(#) in the path. For example, if I type in the path:

```html
http://localhost:6871/#angular
```

When I hit enter it transform into:

```html
http://localhost:6871/#!#angular
```

Because of this issue my routes can never be reach. Has anyone ran into this before? Any suggestions would be great. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs 1.6.0 (latest now) routes not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following after route configurations:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix(' ');
```