# AngularJs Routing isn't working as expected

Tags: angularjs, adminlte

**Please find my demo example on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MUxPMzqpNNZyt9pe2cAz?p=preview).**

I tried to combine the AdminLTE template with AngularJs Routing. So far I defined the routing rules as usual (app.js)

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "subpage0.html"
        })
        .when("/subpage1", {
              templateUrl: "subpage1.html"
        })
        .when("/subpage2", {
            templateUrl: "subpage2.html"
        })
 ...
```

And I set the corresponding links in my sidebar (index.html)

```
<ul class="nav sidebar-menu">
                <li class="active"><a href="#subpage1"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Menu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#subpage2"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Menu2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#subpage3"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Menu3</a></li>
</ul>
```

But unfortunately the angular app always routes to the first case -> subpage0.html

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show your module?

Comment: @cnorthfield You can find this `var app = angular.module('rfidFrontend', ["ngRoute"]);` in the app.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41213016/4314952. It is necessary to add the following config:

```
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
 $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);
```

Updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/E7ZngC5nRVoFuo2yqVuG?p=preview).