# Not getting data in ng-view tabs on using ngRoute.?

Tags: angular, ngroute

I am getting some strange url like this
`http://localhost/bootstrap/aroute/index.html#!#%2Fstudent` instead of

`http://localhost/bootstrap/aroute/index.html#/student` and also not getting the data on the page from templates.

My angular code is like this

`function RouteConfig($routeProvider){

```
        $routeProvider
            .when('/home',{

            templateUrl : 'home.html',
                controller : 'MainController'
            })
            .when('student',{
                templateUrl : '/student.html',
                controller : 'MainController'
            })
            .when('courses',{
                templateUrl : '/courses.html',
                controller : 'MainController'
            });
    }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Include **`$locationProvider.hashPrefix('');`** in your config.

```
function RouteConfig($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
        $routeProvider
            .when('/home',{
            templateUrl : 'home.html',
                controller : 'MainController'
            })
            .when('student',{
                templateUrl : '/student.html',
                controller : 'MainController'
            })
            .when('courses',{
                templateUrl : '/courses.html',
                controller : 'MainController'
            });
    }
```

Comment: Why is that so.?

Comment: @RinkuMalik read it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working