# Routing in AngularJS not working without ! (With #! it works)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am using AngularJS 1.6.4. I have a server spun up @8080 port (just making sure not to miss anything). Below is my code:

**app.js**

```
 //Defines the root module, initialize with additional dependencies
angular.module("MyPhoneApp", ['ngRoute']);
angular.module("MyPhoneApp").component('greetUser', {
    template: 'Hello, {{$ctrl.user}}!',
    controller: function GreetUserController() {
        this.user = 'world';
    }
});

angular.module("MyPhoneApp").component('phoneList', {
    templateUrl: 'app/phoneList.template.html',
    controller: ['$http', function PhoneListController($http){
        var self = this;
        self.criteria = "model";
        $http.get("app/phones.json").then(function(response){
            self.phones = response.data;
        });
    }]
});

//Code for phone-detail snippet
angular.module("MyPhoneApp").component('phoneDetail', {
    template: 'Hello world from Phone Detail component! {{$ctrl.phoneId}}',
    controller: ['$routeParams',
        function PhoneDetailController($routeParams) {
            this.phoneId = $routeParams.phoneId;
        }
    ]
});


//Routing code, to be seperated in different file named app.config.js
angular.module("MyPhoneApp").config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', 
    function config($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            required : true,
            requireBase : false
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/phones', {template:'<phone-list></phone-list>'})
                      .when('/phones/:phoneId', {template: '<phone-detail></phone-detail>'})
                      .otherwise('/phones');
    }   
]);
```

**phoneList.template.html**

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="$ctrl.query" placeholder="Search Phones"><br/>
<select name="type" id="" ng-model="$ctrl.criteria" class="form-control" placeholder="Select Filter Criteria">
    <option value="maker" >By Manufacturer</option>
    <option value="model">By Model</option>
</select>
<ul type="none">
    <li ng-repeat="phone in $ctrl.phones | filter:$ctrl.query | orderBy:$ctrl.criteria" class="panel panel-success">
        <a href="#!/phones/{{phone.id}}" class="thumb">
            <img ng-src="{{phone.image}}" alt="{{phone.model}}" height="180px" width="150px"/>
        </a>
        <a href="#!/phones/1">
            {{phone.maker}} : {{phone.model}}
        </a><br/>
        {{phone.desc}}
    </li>
    <li>
        Number of phones : {{$ctrl.phones.length}}
    </li>
</ul>
<pre>{{$ctrl.phones | filter:$ctrl.query | orderBy:$ctrl.criteria | json}}</pre>
```

and index.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>First AngularJS App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <base href="/"/>
</head>

<body ng-app="MyPhoneApp">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <div ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

The issue is that whenever I have to place links, I have to put them with "#!/someplace/somevalue" and not "#/someplace/somevalue" (notice the exclaimation after hash) to make routing work. Using official AngularJS tutorial for this, I think there is something I am missing. Enabled `html5Mode` also for some ease, but in that case also need to put # on. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this on myself, seeing this:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/aa077e81129c740041438688dff2e8d20c3d7b52

I found that `$locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");` in app.js is the cause, and according to

[angularjs 1.6.0 (latest now) routes not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working)

We should set it to `$locationProvider.hashPrefix("");` to resolve anchor tag URL issues, while removing the hash still a hiccup, will come up wil solution if found.