# ng-app and ngRoute not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I have the following script.js code

```
var app = angular
        .module("Demo", ["ngRoute"])
        .config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when("/home", {
                    templateUrl: "Templates/home.html",
                    controller: "homeController"
                })
                .when("/courses", {
                    templateUrl: "Templates/courses.html",
                    controller: "coursesController"
                })
                .when("/students", {
                    templateUrl: "Templates/students.html",
                    controller: "studentsController"
                })
        })
        .controller("homeController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = "Home Page";
        })
        .controller("coursesController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.courses = ["C#", "VB.NET", "ASP.NET", "SQL Server"];
        })
         .controller("studentsController", function ($scope, $http) {
             $http.get("StudentService.asmx/GetAllStudents")
                                    .then(function (response) {
                                        $scope.students = response.data;
                                    })
         })
```

and the following is the html :

```
      <body ng-app="Demo">
<table style="font-family: Arial">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="header">
            <h1>
                WebSite Header
            </h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="leftMenu">
            <a href="#/home">Home</a>
            <a href="#/courses">Courses</a>
            <a href="#/students">Students</a>
        </td>
        <td class="mainContent">
            <ng-view></ng-view>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="footer">
            <b>Website Footer</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The routing does not work for the above href links. My partial pages consumes the properties of $Scope in the script.js file. But home.html never get loaded after clicking the link. Please help with why ng-app, ng-view, and ngRoute do not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the hashes in your `<a>` tags.

Comment: I dropped the hashes in the <a> tags, but I got 404 errors

Answer (score 0):

it works now since I updated the code as following:
    var app = angular.module('Demo', ['ngRoute'])
      .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
          $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');//this helped fix a bug with angular 1.6.1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working the routing links were not working but this $locationProvider variable change fixed it.
          $routeProvider
          .when('/home', {
              templateUrl: 'Templates/home.html',
              controller: 'homeController'
          })
          .when('/courses', {
              templateUrl: 'Templates/courses.html',
              controller: 'coursesController'
          })
          .when('/students', {
              templateUrl: 'Templates/students.html',
              controller: 'studentsController'
          });
      })