# how to open a page from angularjs app using a new routing page URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular js application and I would like to add a new page which will be accessible from a new URL. This page contains data from a web service.

How can I use $location to add a new URL and to get my page informations from a different path.

I do the following:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#when-should-i-use-location-

```
function monitoringCtrl($scope, $cookieStore) {
    $scope.$root.isActive = true;
    $location.path('/monitoring');
    $location.replace();
}
```

when I tried the path : http://loccalhost:8080/#/monitoring, this will redirect me to the first page of my app, and not my page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which UI-Router version? 0.X or 1.X? Which Version of AngularJS? The default hash bang was changed to `#!` instead of `#`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs 1.6.0 (latest now) routes not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41211875/angularjs-1-6-0-latest-now-routes-not-working)

Comment: @georgeawg C'est la version 1.X ()