# AngularJS regex route for similar url to load different controller and view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I have a similar route that should load a different view and controller based on whether or not the parameter is a number. Example:

- `/artists/2` should `ArtistsIndexController` with a view `/www/artists/index.html`
- `/artists/name` should `ArtistsProfileController` with a view `/www/artists/profile.html`

Ideally I would use something like:

```
$routeProvider.when("/artists/:page", {
  templateUrl: "/www/artists/index.html",
  controller: "ArtistsIndexController"
});

$routeProvider.when("/artists/:name", {
  templateUrl: "/www/artists/profile.html",
  controller: "ArtistsProfileController"
});
```

Where `:page` is a number and `:name` is not.

Note I see a related [github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/918) (found from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685085/angularjs-route-how-to-match-star-as-a-path)) but am wondering if there is a resolution or preferred solution.

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which supports regular expressions for routes (among a slew of other things) which would allow:

```
$stateProvider.state("artists-index", {
  url: "/artists/{page:[0-9]*}",
  templateUrl: "/www/artists/index.html",
  controller: "ArtistsIndexController"
});

$stateProvider.state("artists-profile", {
  url: "/artists/{name}",
  templateUrl: "/www/artists/profile.html",
  controller: "ArtistsProfileController"
});
```

Comment: what is difference between route & state?

Comment: @Apul when I've used ui-router I've always had a route for each state so I just thought of the states as a route. The [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) mention that not every state needs a route but I wouldn't worry about that at first. You can look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) for more details on the concept of a generic state machine as well.

Answer (score 3):

I use a nasty hack, that consist on change the regexp

```
var $route = $routeProvider.$get[$routeProvider.$get.length-1]({$on:function(){}});


$routeProvider.when("/artists/:page", {
  templateUrl: "/www/artists/index.html",
  controller: "ArtistsIndexController"
});

$routeProvider.when("/artists/:name", {
  templateUrl: "/www/artists/profile.html",
  controller: "ArtistsProfileController"
});

$route.routes['/artist/:page'].regexp = /^\/(?:artist\/(\d+))$/
$route.routes['/artist/:page/'].regexp = /^\/(?:artist\/(\d+))\/$/
```

It's ugly but it works fine.
You can change your routes' regexps to make them match whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this as a solution for now and would be interested in alternatives!

1) Create a generic template that will load in a controller and view dynamically:

```
<div ng-controller="controller" ng-include src="templateUrl"></div>
```

In this example I placed this view in `/www/shared/dynamic-controller.html`

2) Create a controller that checks the route params to determine which controller and view to load:

```
angular.module('appName').
  controller('ArtistsDynamicRouteController', ['$scope', '$controller', '$routeParams', function($scope, $controller, $routeParams) {
    if(/^\d+$/.test($routeParams.pageOrId)) {
      // when pageOrId is a page (number) we want to load the ArtistsIndexController
      $scope.controller = $controller('ArtistsIndexController', { $scope: $scope }).constructor;
      $scope.templateUrl = '/www/artists/index.html';
    } else {
      // when pageOrId is an id (non-number) we want to load the ArtistsProfileController
      $scope.controller = $controller('ArtistsProfileController', { $scope: $scope }).constructor;
      $scope.templateUrl = '/www/artists/profile.html';
    }
  }]);
```

3) Use one route regardless of the parameter type:

```
// handles both /artists/2 and /artists/username
$routeProvider.when("/artists/:pageOrName", {
  templateUrl: "/www/shared/dynamic-controller.html",
  controller: "ArtistsDynamicRouteController"
});
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18137810/how-to-eliminate-minification-errors-when-using-controller-in-angularjs) for issues with minification when doing this.