# How to eliminate minification errors when using $controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
angular.module('mainApp').
  controller('dynamicRouteController', ['$scope', '$controller', '$routeParams', function($scope, $controller, $routeParams) {
    if(/^\d+$/.test($routeParams.pageOrName)) {
      $scope.controller = $controller('thisController', { $scope: $scope }).constructor;
      $scope.templateUrl = '/www/thisPage';
    } else {
      $scope.controller = $controller('thatController', { $scope: $scope }).constructor;
      $scope.templateUrl = '/www/thatPage';
    }
  }]);
```

this minifies to:

```
"use strict";
angular.module("mainApp").
controller("dynamicRouteController",["$scope",‌​"$controller","$routeParams",function(a,b,c){
/^\d+$/.test(c.pageOrName)?
(a.contro‌​ller=b("thisController",{$scope:a}).constructor,a.templateUrl="/www/thisPage"):
(a‌​.controller=b("thatController",{$scope:a}).constructor,a.templateUrl="/www/thatPa‌​ge")
}])
```

This is having issues minifying, I think its because of the {$scope : $scope} being altered... First time I have run into this/used this method.  Anyone know a better way to write this so it minifies correctly?

EDIT: so whats happening, is that it is passing the {$scope: a} which is fine, but on that referenced controller, when its minified, that $scope has become a or b or e depending... so if I write the code "pre-minified", meaning I literally find what letter represents $scope in the other controller, I can get it to work, but thats so hacky!  Again, any ideas?

Using Grunt for minification
Angular 1.0.5 ... maybe fixed in later versions?

2nd EDIT:  A decent answer is to throw both controllers into the same file, explicitly... which is ugly... but it works!  so with in one controller, I am declaring 2 sub controllers, which is lame.  If you know of another way please share with the class!

Comment: Just taking a wild guess here but `{"$scope": $scope}`?

Comment: good call Phil, I tried that to no avail, though :(

Comment: There's a comment on the [`$controller`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$controller) doco that has `{$scope: {}}`. Give that a try

Comment: We are on the same track.. tried that as well, it doesn't send the $scope properly, even before minification.

Comment: Just another wild guess `var scope = $scope;` then `$controller('thatController', { $scope: scope }).constructor;` Similar to how one would achieve the same end when testing a controller. Although when testing you tend to use `var scope = $rootScope.$new();`

Comment: couldn't get that to fly either

Comment: Could you provided the code after it is minified? Perhaps that would provide some insight?

Comment: `"use strict";angular.module("mainApp").controller("dynamicRouteController",["$scope","$controller","$routeParams",function(a,b,c){/^\d+$/.test(c.pageOrName)?(a.controller=b("thisController",{$scope:a}).constructor,a.templateUrl="/www/thisPage"):(a.controller=b("thatController",{$scope:a}).constructor,a.templateUrl="/www/thatPage")}])`

Comment: What tool are you using for minification?

Comment: grunt's minifictation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was working on this issue with @mclenithan and what we came up with is:

```
$scope.controller = ['$scope', 'service1', 'service2', 
    $controller('thisController', { $scope: $scope }).constructor];
```

The main issue was the controllers `thisController` and `thatController` had more parameters to inject than just `$scope` (in this example it expects `service1` and `service2`).

The `$controller(...).constructor` was returning the minified controller function with the parameters renamed to a, b, c, d, etc. When Angular was trying to instantiate the controller it had issues trying to find the correct services to inject.

Using the [array notation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.$injector#thearraynotation) instead of just the controller function fixed the issue. See [a note on minification](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#anoteonminification) in the tutorial for more info.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131834/angularjs-regex-route-for-similar-url-to-load-different-controller-and-view) for context on what we were trying to do to begin with.