# AngularJS Routing based on param

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm using the `$routeProvider` and I want the route to load a different view depending on what is passed:

```
when('/tx/:txid', {
  templateUrl: '/views/tx/view.html'
}).
```

If `txid` matches a certain pattern, it should load one view. If it matches a different pattern, it should load a different view. Is this possible?

Comment: see this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131834/angularjs-regex-route-for-similar-url-to-load-different-controller-and-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at dynamic templates.

```
when('/tx/:txid', 
    {   
      controller:ctrl, 
      templateUrl: function(params){ 
         // your logic here...
         return '/tx/diferentview/' + params.txid; 
      }
    }
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Instead of passing the `txid`, I can do a check of some kind, like if `params.txid` is numeric, then return View1 or else View2, right?

Comment: you should be able to, yes.  in the above example, params.txid can be evaluated independently

Comment: Yes you can have any logic you want there, and return the correct view.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function for dynamic views:

```
.when('/tx/:txid', {
    templateUrl: function(routeParams) {
        // return necessary view based on route params
        return '/views/tx/view.html'; 
    }
})
```

From [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider):

> If templateUrl is a function, it will be called with the following parameters:
>   {Array.} - route parameters extracted from the current $location.path() by applying the current route