# AngularJS routing pattern

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I have the following routing:

```
.when('/stories/:action/:assetId', {
  templateUrl: 'sometpl.html',
  controller: 'ctrl'
}
```

now... how to make it that 'action' can match only specified group of words, for example ['read', 'list'].

Answer (score 0):

Please see [18131834](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131834/angularjs-regex-route-for-similar-url-to-load-different-controller-and-view), which has this answer:

Another way is to use the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which supports regular expressions for route params:

```
$stateProvider.state("artists-index", {
    url: "/artists/{page:[0-9]*}",
    templateUrl: "/www/artists/index.html",
    controller: "ArtistsIndexController"
});

$stateProvider.state("artists-profile", {
    url: "/artists/{name}",
    templateUrl: "/www/artists/profile.html",
    controller: "ArtistsProfileController"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this: In the controller you get the action and store into a varibale ( I supose you already did that ), then you check if that variable is in an array of strings (supported actions). Like:

```
String action = 'read'; // Action from url
String supportedActions = ['read', 'list']
boolean contains = false;
for (String item : supportedActions) {
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(item)) {
       contains = true;
       switch(action){
           case 'read':{
               /* Do your magic */
           }
           case 'list':{
               /* Do more magic */
           }
       }
    } 
}
if(!contains){
    /* I don't know that action */
}
```