# AngularJS 1.0.7 routeParams parse

Tags: angularjs

I have this rule in my app.js:

```
$routeProvider.when('/:language/rental-:type-:departure', {templateUrl: 'partials/rental.html', controller: 'itemCtrl'});
```

When user type a url like: `/en/rental-houses-santa-cruz-tenerife`

Then:

```
var type = $routeParams.type;     # houses-santa-cruz                                  
var departure = $routeParams.departure; # tenerife
```

When my expected result is:

```
type = houses
departure = santa-cruz-tenerife
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: It very hard to predict by `router engine` to take value upto which `-`(hyphen).. Plunkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/1BDG9C0r0f8mrcCQeJYT?p=preview

Comment: Is there a reason why you do not use slash character to separate type and departure? like *.../en/rental/houses/santa-cruz-tenerif* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to angular 1.2 to do this.

The standard way of handling this in angular is through ngRoute and regular expressions (like is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131834/angularjs-regex-route-for-similar-url-to-load-different-controller-and-view) and [here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/BMyuhhTexP6bJLPIULwe)), but angular 1.0.8 doesn't allow you to use regular expressions at all in the route patterns ([see here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/angular.js), ctrl+f for switchRouteMatcher).

You could fork angular 1.0.8 and add update the `switchRouteMatcher` method too if upgrading your version to 1.2 is out of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Upgrade to Angular 1.2 is not an option right now. I had a look at switchRouteMatcher but honestly at first sight looks chinese to me. I´m also afraid to update that core code. Any help or other idea is appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, just compare it  to the same method in Angular 1.2 - it looked like only a couple lines are different, and then you'll be able to take advantage of that `.regexp` property like in the examples.