# $routeProvider: Undefined number of IDs

Tags: angularjs, routes, route-provider

in my angularjs app my path gets build like so:

When the user clicks a submenu item the index of the item is added to the path. The depth of the menu is not specified.

So if the user clicks though all the menus the path could look like this:

`.../#/settings/0/2/0/3/2`

How can I set up the $routeProvider so the number of IDs doesn't matter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - Route - How to match star (\*) as a path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685085/angularjs-route-how-to-match-star-as-a-path)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parameters, you could use a query, see [$routeParams](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeParams):

`/#/settings?ids=0,2,0,3,2`