# AngularJS regex in route to restrict some parameters to be int type

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, route-provider, ngroute

I've been looking for a lot of references like:

[AngularJS regex route for similar url to load different controller and view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131834/angularjs-regex-route-for-similar-url-to-load-different-controller-and-view)

[AngularJS - Route - How to match star (*) as a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685085/angularjs-route-how-to-match-star-as-a-path)

These are questions 1-2 years ago. I'm using AngularJS v1.2.16 and I'd want to know if AngularJS with my version or upper already supports regex pattern in path param.

I mean. I have these two routes

```
$routeProvider
.when("/:color/:number", {
  templateUrl: "/view/example/index.html",
  controller: "ColorController"
})
.when("/:artist/:name", {
  templateUrl: "/view/example/index.html",
  controller: "ColorController"
});
```

Then, I'd like to enter a pattern to restrict a *:number* to be an integer number but the controller and view are the same in both cases, i.e.

```
$routeProvider
.when("/:color/:[0-9]", {
  templateUrl: "/view/example/index.html",
  controller: "ColorController"
});
.when("/:artist/:name", {
  templateUrl: "/view/example/index.html",
  controller: "ColorController"
});
```

Or something like that. Is it already possible with AngularJS *$routeProvider*?

I know the [AngularUI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) but I'd wish to use $routeProvider if possible

Any ideas?